# I'm trying to generate an onclick method within javascript generated html and it's giving me some very weird results

Tags: javascript, html

So here's the line

```
'<button onclick="deleteElement("' + instrument.name + '")">Delete this instrument</button>'
```

I was expecting this to just output to the html the following, when given the instrument "Clean Male Tenor Vocals"

```
<button onclick="deleteElement("Clean Male Tenor Vocals")">Delete this instrument</button>
```

However, things stopped working, and when i checked what html it was actually generating in the inspector, it instead has decided to generate the following.

```
<button onclick="deleteElement(" clean="" tenor="" male="" vocals")"="">Delete this instrument</button>
```

I'm very confused, and cannot figure out what's going on here.

I assume there is some small thing that i'm missing, or don't understand about javascript or html, i am still fairly new to web dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overusing the double-quote, which is confusing the HTML parser.

A good rule of thumb: use double-quotes for HTML elements, single quotes for JavaScript. Or even better, use the backtick to make a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

An example using the backtick:

```js
let instrument = { name: 'Clean Male Tenor Vocals' };
let myString =
  `<button onclick="deleteElement('${instrument.name}')">Delete this instrument</button>`
```

This will produce:

```html
<button onclick="deleteElement('Clean Male Tenor Vocals')">Delete this instrument</button>
```

Comment: Ah, i see, silly me. That makes sense, i will be more mindful of that in the future. Thank you! Also, what are those "let" keywords used for?

Comment: @RobHoover I just threw that "let" in there to declare and set instrument.name. It should read `let instrument = { name: 'Clean Male Tenor Vocals' }`

Comment: I see, thank you! I have never seen the '${ }' thing used before, what do you call that, so i can look into that more?

Comment: @RobHoover It’s called a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You would just suggest the following approach:

using data- attribute to store the unique identifier like so

```
`<button data-instrument="${instrument.name}" class="delete-instrument-btn">Delete this instrument</button>`
```

then in the script, you are shipping in your HTML file, attach click event listener

```
// run the following script once the HTML has been fully rendered
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
 function handleDeleteInstrument(ev) {
  const instrument = ev.target.dataset.instrument;
  if (
    instrument === undefined || 
    instrument === null      ||
    instrument.length === 0
  ) {
    console.log('Invalid instrument name provided')
    return;
  }
  deleteElement(instrument);
 }

 Array
  .from(document.querySelectorAll('.delete-instrument-btn'))
  .forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', handleDeleteInstrument);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want create element you can do this

```js
function create(){
let container = document.getElementById('container');
let content = 'text content';   
  container.innerText = content;
  return container
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
</div>  
 <button onClick='create()'>create</button>
```

Comment: Can you provide more details or tell us what you want to do?